# TagHelpers Intellisense not working with dnx46 in vNext beta8

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I am not able to get TagHelpers Colorization and Intellisense to work in ASP.NET vNext WebToolsExtensionsVS14 Beta 8 when using the dnx46 framework.

NOTE: The project does build, run and TagHelpers are correctly processed on the server. This issue only affects design-time.

Steps I used:

1. File >> New Project - with the default project options (using .Net Framework 4.6) and Web Application template:
2. View the _Layout.cshtml, _ViewImports.chhtml, and project.json as follows:
   [Colorization and Intellisense is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vt3lZ.png)
3. Modify the project.json frameworks from "dnx451" to "dnx46" and save. Allow the references to update. Close the _Layout.cshtml. Rebuild the solution.
4. View the _Layout.cshtml:
   [Colorization and Intellisense NOT working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CaHt.png)

Questions:

1. Is anyone else having this issue?
2. Has anyone figured out a work around?

Answer (score 0):

Known issue. It's being tracked [here](https://github.com/aspnet/RazorTooling/issues/19)

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved in the RC1.

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-windows.html